# Have I really proved Exercise 23.5 in Tu's Manifolds, or how to amend this proof?

Tags: solution-verification, differential-topology, differential-forms, orientation

In the following proof, I believe I have only showed that the $2$-form given equals the orientation form $\omega$ on the intersection $U_x\cap U_y\cap U_z$. I'm not sure if I can do the same `trick' involving $\frac{dy\wedge dz}{x}, \frac{dz\wedge dx}{y}$, and $\frac{dx\wedge dy}{z}$ in just the open sets $U_x, U_y$, and $U_z$ (no triple intersection) since these expressions are not defined away from where the denominator of each is nonzero. I am wondering whether I have written enough to show that the 2-form given really equals $\omega$ in $U_x, U_y$, or $U_z$ (away from the triple intersection) since the vanishing of $x,y,$ or $z$ are each a codimension 1 condition.

**Exercise 23.5**: Show that on $S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$, we have that the 2-form $xdy\wedge dz + y dz\wedge dx + z dx\wedge dy$ equals the orientation form

$$\omega = \begin{cases} \frac{dx \wedge dy}{z} & \text{ on }z\neq 0,\\ \frac{dy\wedge dz}{x} & \text{ on }x \neq 0,\\ \frac{dz\wedge dx}{y} & \text{ on }y\neq 0. \end{cases} $$

*Proof*
$S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is defined as $S^2 := f^{-1}(0)$ where $f(x,y,z):= x^2+y^2+z^2-1$. Then $f=0$ implies $df = 2xdx+2ydy+2zdz=0$, so that
\begin{align*}
    dx &= \frac{-ydy-zdz}{x} &\text{ on } x\neq 0, \\
    dy &= \frac{-xdx-zdz}{y} & \text{ on }y\neq 0,  &\text{ and }\\
    dz &= \frac{-xdx-ydy}{z} & \text{ on }z\neq 0.
\end{align*}

From these relations, we have on $U_x$ that $dx \wedge dy= \frac{-z}{x}dz\wedge dy$, and $dx \wedge dz = \frac{-y}{x}dy\wedge dz$.

On $U_y$, $dy\wedge dx = \frac{-z}{y}dz\wedge dx$ and $dy\wedge dz = \frac{-x}{y}dx\wedge dz$.

On $U_z$, $dz\wedge dx = \frac{-y}{z}dy\wedge dx$ and $dz\wedge dy = \frac{-x}{z}dx\wedge dy$.

From $\frac{dx\wedge dy}{f_z} = \frac{dy\wedge dz}{f_x} = \frac{dz\wedge dx}{f_y}$ on $U_x \cap U_y\cap U_z$ [construction of non-vanishing n-form on pre-image of regular value where $f_x, f_y$ and $f_z$ are partial derivatives] we have

\begin{align*}
    \frac{dy\wedge dz}{2x} = \frac{dz\wedge dx}{2y} = \frac{dx\wedge dy}{2z}.
\end{align*}

Multiplying through by 2 gives

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{dy\wedge dz}{x} = \frac{dz\wedge dx}{y} = \frac{dx\wedge dy}{z}.
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

On $U_x\cap U_y\cap U_z$, we have

$$(xdy\wedge dz + ydz\wedge dx + zdx\wedge dy)|_{U_x} = x^2 (\frac{dy\wedge dz}{x}) + y^2(\frac{dz\wedge dx}{y}) + z^2 (\frac{dx\wedge dy}{z}) \\
                 = (x^2+y^2+z^2) ( \frac{dy\wedge dz}{x}) \hspace{2cm}\text{ by above equation}\\
                  = \frac{dy\wedge dz}{x} \text{ since } x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$$

This shows that $\omega = xdy\wedge dz + ydz\wedge dx + zdx\wedge dy$ on $U_x\cap U_y \cap U_z$, and since the substitutions in Equation (1) hold on any overlaps where the expressions are well-defined, we are free to make the same substitution in $U_x$, $U_y$ and $U_z$. *End Proof*

Comment: This looks good. But why do you need lines 9-11 of the proof? Doesn't the display after "Multiplying through by 2 gives" follow from the equations given in lines 6-8?

Comment: Maybe you are not answering what I have asked because I have not asked it clearly: I can show that the 2-form given above and the orientation form $\omega$ agree on the triple intersection $U_x\cap U_y\cap U_z$. Does the argument I gave also show that they are equal on just $U_x$, or just $U_y$, or just $U_z$?

Comment: We can't even write $(dz\wedge dx)/y$ in all of $U_x$, so I don't believe this actually works. That is what I am having an issue with. Can we just (or, do you?) just pretend like there is no issue, and say we can substitute $(dy\wedge dz)/x$ for $(dz\wedge dx)/y$ and $(dx\wedge dy)/z$ in $U_x$, even though these latter two expressions  $(dz\wedge dx)/y$ and $(dx\wedge dy)/z$ are not defined?

Comment: I assume you've written out the problem exactly as stated in the book. In the statement, it is not a priori known that the three different formulas for $\omega$ are in fact equal on the intersection. So I don't think the problem is properly stated. In fact, you are given three different $2$-forms (the three forms on the right side of the equation "defining" $\omega$). You then want to show that each one is equal to $x\,dy\wedge dz + y\,dz\wedge dx + z\,dx\wedge dy$. You have a correct proof for the first equality. The others follow by permuting the names of the variables.

Comment: So your answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, I've already shown that $\omega$ agrees on intersections (``glues together nicely"). 

But what I've written is only valid on the triple intersection $U_x\cap U_y\cap U_z$, so why should this hold on just $U_x$ or just $U_y$ or just $U_z$?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. One way to deal with this is to observe that each side of the equation extends smoothly to $U_x$ and, by taking limits, the equation has to hold for the extended forms.

Comment: This is what I am missing, thank you very much.